# What kinds of css hack for IE do you know?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I know these so far:

*width:to hack all IE

_width:to hack IE6 only

Can you guys continue?

Comment: I assume you mean "selector hacks"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use selector hacks to target IE; use [conditional comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(VS.85).aspx). It's what they're for (amongst other things).

People only ever used selector hacks to target or exclude IE because they didn't know about conditional comments; now we are aware of them, there is no reason to continue using selector hacks.

Comment: +1. Conditional comments are, in the imperfect world of web design, an awesome tool and definitely more stable than hacks.

Comment: Can Conditional comments be put inside css files?

Comment: No, you use CCs to include the CSS file that contains the fixes necessary for IE. If you look at my profile, you'll find a link to my site; view the source and you'll see that in the head of the page I use a CC to include a stylesheet that contains the things that only IE 6 & 7 need. Alternatively, look at a site I did some work on to see their use in a commercial environment: http://www.xfm.co.uk/

Answer (score 2):

[The Ultimate IE Hack Guide](http://cavemonkey50.com/2005/12/the-ultimate-ie-hack-guide/).